# Desktop non-HTML player for Premium+ users?

Tags: deezer

I have a headless PC connected to my stereo system. I would like to create a command-line Deezer player for it. Is it possible without launching web browser? Does the API always return only 30s previews, even for Premium+ users?

EDIT:
To clarify the question: I'm looking for a way to get URL of a full-length MP3 using Deezer API. I only see references to 30s previews in Deezer API Specification. Does it mean that I can't get URL to full-length MP3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Full track streaming is only available thru the SDKs (JS, iOS, Android), so you'll have to launch a web browser. You can't get the full mp3s from the API directly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2831696/julaie. can i play Deezer Streaming Song by my player Created in IOS Core Audio Unit?

Comment: @ julaie please help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23775236/is-it-possible-to-get-the-audio-stream-using-dezzer-sdk-and-process-raw-data-usi

Comment: Is it possible to open up the API to support full-length MP3 URLs for certified partners of Deezer?

Answer (score 0):

See the API Specifications [Deezer API](http://developers.deezer.com/api).

You can implement it to a own software. If you would like to create an player, you need mostly MP3-Librarys to play the File.

You dont specific in which language you need to implement a Player. We can't give you special answers to that, only global informations: The API.

Here are the URL's from Preview and Full-Song:

```
var SOUND_STREAM_GATEWAY = 'http://proxy-{0}-v3.deezer.com/stream/{1}/';
var SOUND_PREVIEW_GATEWAY = 'http://cdn-preview-{0}.deezer.com/stream/{1}-{2}.mp3';
```

Comment: If I understand the API Specifications correctly, there's no way to get link to the full MP3. The track object only gives url to Deezer page and to the 30s preview. Same for radio/tracks method.
Am I missing something?
I want to implement the Player in Python using Qt's QMediaPlayer, but I know how to do this. I simply don't know how to get url to full-length MP3 using Deezer API.

Comment: Good question. Currently i search for it on the website and on the embedded Flash-Player. You can also check out the source from http://www.showmycode.com/?9a95de1152045809579e529f393281f8

Comment: This code isn't really helpful. It looks like the insteresting magic happens in URLBuilder. Also after looking at Network tab of Firefox Developer tools while starting a new track, I believe it's not possible to get an URL from API, as it downloads a bunch of ~530KB .flv parts of the track.

Comment: You dont get the request of the original song in your network tab because the song will load over the flash embedded player!